# I want to have a border-bottom in a ul list

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I'm working on my responsive with a breakpoint at 576px

I want to have what's here in this first pic without any space in the border-bottom and whith my two elements taking all the width :[menu li hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXQx6.png)

But for now what i have is this :
[my menu li - with space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Ych.png)

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance! have a nice day!

here's my code so far:

```css
/*-------------------Header desktop size-------------------*/
.header {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1440px;
}

.header div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.header img {
    margin: 10px 60px 0px 55px;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 80px 0 0;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-items {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu-items:hover {
    color: #0065fc;
}

.menu li {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 60px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}

/*-------------------Header mobile size-------------------*/

@media all and ( max-width: 576px) {

/*-- header --*/

    .menu {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

    .menu nav {
        position: relative;
        flex-basis: 100%;
        order: 2;
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-basis: 100%;
        order: 2;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        right: 160px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: -30px;     
    }

    .menu-items {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        width: 250px;
    }

    .menu-items:hover {
        border-bottom-color: #0065FC;
    }

    .sign-up {
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        color: #0065fc;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 165px;
        transition: all 0.4s;
        right: 9px;
    }
   }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div>
    <div><a href="#" class="header-logo"></a>
      <img src="images/logo/Reservia.svg" alt="Logo Reservia">
    </div>
                
     <nav class="menu">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#search-lodging" class="menu-items" title="Hébergements">Hébergements</a></li>
          <li><a href="#search-activities" class="menu-items" title="Activités">Activités</a></li>
       </ul>
      
      <a href="#" class="sign-up" title="S'inscrire <strong>S'inscrire</strong></a>
       
     </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set li margin to 0px or 1px if you want?

```css
/*-------------------Header desktop size-------------------*/

.header {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.header div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.header img {
  margin: 10px 60px 0px 55px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 80px 0 0;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-items {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu-items:hover {
  color: #0065fc;
}

.menu li {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/*-------------------Header mobile size-------------------*/

@media all and ( max-width: 576px) {
  /*-- header --*/
  .menu {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .menu nav {
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    right: 160px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin-right: 1px; /* Just set margin to 0? OR 1 if you want? */
  }
  .menu-items {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  .menu-items:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #0065FC;
  }
  .sign-up {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #0065fc;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 165px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    right: 9px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="header-logo"></a>
      <img src="images/logo/Reservia.svg" alt="Logo Reservia">
    </div>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#search-lodging" class="menu-items" title="Hébergements">Hébergements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#search-activities" class="menu-items" title="Activités">Activités</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" class="sign-up" title="S'inscrire <strong>S'inscrire</strong></a>
       
     </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i've tried but now I have this : ibb.co/ZTDcFQH

Comment: Can you give us the website? It will be really easy to fix it there directly.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue. you just have to remove `margin-right` from your `media query` and align your text center.

**Note**: Please test it in `576px` or less to see the corrections

```css
.header {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.header div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.header img {
  margin: 10px 60px 0px 55px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 80px 0 0;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-items {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu-items:hover {
  color: #0065fc;
}

.menu li {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/*-------------------Header mobile size-------------------*/

@media all and (max-width: 576px) {

  /*-- header --*/

  .menu {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

  .menu nav {
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
  }

  .menu ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    right: 160px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -30px;
  }

  .menu-items {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 250px;
  }

  .menu-items:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #0065FC;
  }

  .menu li {
    margin-right: unset;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .sign-up {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #0065fc;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 165px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    right: 9px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div>
    <div><a href="#" class="header-logo"></a>
      <img src="images/logo/Reservia.svg" alt="Logo Reservia">
    </div>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#search-lodging" class="menu-items" title="Hébergements">Hébergements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#search-activities" class="menu-items" title="Activités">Activités</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" class="sign-up" title="S'inscrire <strong>S'inscrire</strong></a>
       
     </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5rdsvcL/)

Comment: thank you for your help. i've tried but now I have this : https://ibb.co/ZTDcFQH

Comment: @Rowena please attach your current code to fiddle so I can see what have you done wrong.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for trying to help!
I've made some changes but still not what i'm supposed to have

I have this : https://ibb.co/6YvpvZL
And  I want this:  https://ibb.co/hfsMPtk

But I have an issue with my menu because when the resolution gets down it disapears and normally it shouldn't

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/8rfq135d/2/

Comment: @Rowena check out this `fiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/8txna2br/

Answer (score 0):

Your `.menu li` style has a margin-right value of 60px, which means all list elements will have that margin.

You can probably add the same selector inside your media query with:

```
.menu li {
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

The padding replaces the margin spacing so the text in the list items don't get pushed up against each other

You should be able to see this in your browser's developer tools. If you select an element in the `Elements` view it shows all the styles being applied and which classes.

Comment: thank you for your help. i've tried but now I have this : ibb.co/ZTDcFQH

Comment: Ok, so now to get the elements to space out more, you should add some padding to them, so that the text doesn't touch, but the actual `<li>` elements extend to touch each other.
Assuming you want the same sort of value you had before, setting `padding-left: 30px;` and `padding-right: 30px;` in the same selector should work